# Match multiple binary trees in another big binary tree

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, tree, pattern-matching, string-matching

I was wondering if there is any efficient algorithm for finding matches for a set S = {t_1, t_2, ..., t_n} of small **binary-trees** in a big **binary-tree** T? The binary trees here are ordered and labeled, i.e., every node has a label and the left/right child cannot be swapped.

A "match" of t_i in T means that there is a subtree (a connected component) of T being identical to t_i.

The naive method would be scanning over every node of T and trying to match t_1, t_2, ..., one by one. I was thinking if there is anything like *Aho-Croskik* string matching algorithm, which locates a set of short strings (patterns) in a long text by linear time complexity (w.r.t. the sum of lengths of all the pattern strings and text.)

Thanks in advance. Any pointers to references etc would also be much appreciated!

Comment: Maybe you can write down the trees using in-order traversal and then use string matching(e.g. with Aho-Corasick as you suggest). Keep in mind the even if the in-order traversal of a tree is a substring of the big tree this still does not mean the tree is matched. Still this should optimize the naive approach I think

Comment: The in order traversal to string idea works better if you parenthesise each subtree; then a matching substring is a matching tree.

Answer (score 0):

Represent subtree and a big tree in terms of inorder and postorder(or preorder) traversal strings. If you find that both inorder, postorder(or preorder) strings are substrings of inorder, postorder of big tree then there is a match(you can check whether it is substring or not using kmp in linear time complexity).